# Outlining a Stroke Doesn't Work Properly in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, stroke

When I try to outline the stroke in the screenshot below, the tip of the line gets changed. Please help me here? What should I do to get the exact image, but filled instead of stroked.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Hi Siamak. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, I can't replicate the problem. When I expand a stroke I get [the expected result](https://i.imgur.com/BaKrUv4.png).

Comment: Most likely you have 2 points on top of eachother

Answer (score 2):

This is a **bug** which happens for paths drawn with the pen tool and start with the `Default` appearance applied. I know it exists in AICS6 and a couple of the CC versions. I'm not booted into a machine running CC2018 to test that version at the moment. But it absolutely occurs in CS6 and CC2017 / Mac.

It only happens if the path is *manually* created with the Pen Tool and under *specific* circumstances. Most often you'll see this if you:

1. Create the path with the Pen Tool
2. Initially the path had the `Default` appearance applied (1pt black stroke and a white fill)
3. You removed the fill, added the caps, set the stroke weight (any order)
4. *Then* expanding/outlining *may* result in the lost end cap.

Note that pretty much *all of these* have to be in play to see the issue most of the time. It's one of those bugs that is kind of obscure, but not that rare. If you know what I mean.

I know in AICS6 *and* AICC2017, the above steps will result in the issue every time.

So, to get around it...

- Set the **appearance first**. Set the stroke width, cap, and the fill *before* you draw anything. And **make certain** `New Art Has Basic Appearance` is **not** set in the **Appearance Panel Menu**. Then draw your path with the Pen Tool and the bug *should* not present itself. This often means you need to do this and *redraw* the path. It's difficult to correct on an existing path if it's happening already.
- Create the path by editing shapes (i.e. Daiello's method) and the issue should not appear.
- For an *existing path*, if you really don't want to redraw.... Use `Object > Flatten Transparency` rather than `Outline Stroke` (or `Expand`). This keeps the round caps but may result in *way* more anchor points than it should.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, make sure all ending nodes of the stroke are curve nodes.
Here's the result with the last stroke being a sharp node
The stroke before expanding:

[image]

And after expanding

[image]

Now, if we make sure that all end nodes are curve nodes:

[image]

Expanding results on this:

[image]

Is annoying but is what I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I've run across a few times.

You can get around it by using the Anchor Point tool (Shortcut: Shift–C) and adding a curve to the end that's giving you trouble.

It doesn't actually need to be curved, but just using the Anchor Point tool to add a "straight-curve" (if thats a thing lol) by pulling out the  bezier curve nodes, that should do the trick.[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Please don't leave thanks as an answer. If you want to add an answer please format it as one.  Once you have enough reputation you will be able to leave comments.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the tip @BillyKerr and joojaa